# Изменение названия ресурсов

Tags: visual-studio, ресурсы

Допустим, я добавил какой-то ресурс в проект.

И я решил его переименовать. Переименовал в менеджере. А как переименовать сам файл? Если переименовать его физически, то при компиляции будет ругань, что файл не найден... Получается нужно ручками редактировать `resx`-файл или все таки можно сделать через какую-то менюшку?